# Change gunzip temporary directory while used in pipe

Tags: linux, temporary-files, gunzip

**Background**

I'm working on an mysql server with those hdd partitions:

```
...
/dev/vdd       99G     58G   39G   61% /var/lib/mysql
tmpfs         2,4G       0  2,4G    0% /tmp
...
```

I need to import a mysql dump into my database. Therefore I use the following syntax:

```
gunzip -c sql_dump.sql.gz | mysql -uDB_USER -p DB_NAME
```

In general this works but my `sql_dump.sql.gz` file will be over 5GB when extracted.

The command above will fail with `gzip: /home/.../sql_dump.sql.gz: No space left on device`. I think this is not related to the `mysql` partiton which has enough space, but the `/tmp` partition which does only have 2.4GB free.

For now I did go ahead an moved the file to the `/var/lib/mysql` parition which has enough free space. gunzip my file there, start the mysql import and removed the compressed and uncompressed files afterward.

**Question**

I was asking myself if there is any way I can force `gunzip` to temporary change the default temporary target location, which is `/tmp/` by default. So that `gunzip -c sql_dump.sql.gz | ...` does not store the extracted file under `/tmp/` but under `/var/lib/mysql` while extracting the file. Something like this:

```
export "GZIP_TMP_DIR=/var/lib/mysql/"
gunzip -c sql_dump.sql.gz | mysql -uDB_USER -p DB_NAME
```

Is this even possbile ? I searched a lot but could not find anything that would solve this specific need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the desired temporary directory in environment variable `TMPDIR` (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TMPDIR).

Comment: Could you elaborate on why this is? My HPC admin also gave me this fix, but I've not been able to find an easy explanation on why/how `gzip`/`gunzip` uses `$TMPDIR`, especially since you can see the file being output in (not really?) real-time.